# firebase phone auth android Crashing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

so I am using firebase database and Auth, I am trying to build Phone Auth but for some reason the app is crashing.. not sure why..
I am new to programming with android studio and first timer on Firebase database, not sure why the app is crashing but its crashing after I am pressing a button that activate verifySignInCode() insta crash after it, it does send an email with code a 
Log cat Error is here

```
09-15 20:39:41.804 22046-22046/com.example.erelpc.calltest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.erelpc.calltest, PID: 22046
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, ortemprary proof.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.<init>(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source:33)
        at com.example.erelpc.calltest.MainActivity.verifySignInCode(MainActivity.java:92)
        at com.example.erelpc.calltest.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:28)
        at com.example.erelpc.calltest.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6877)
```

And Here is the MainActivity

```
    /// SMS Handler
    private void sendVerificationCode(){
        String phone = etphonenumber.getText().toString();
        if (phone.isEmpty()) {
            etphonenumber.setError("Enter a Phone Number!");
            etphonenumber.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (phone.length() != 9){
            etphonenumber.setError("Please Enter a valid Number!");
            etphonenumber.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        phone = "+972" + phone;
        Intent intent =  new Intent(this, loginsuccess.class);
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phone,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    }
    private void verifySignInCode(){

        String code = etcodeveri.getText().toString();
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codesent, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            codesent = s;
        }
    };


    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            registerModule();
                        } else {
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Unsuccess!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }  
    public void registerModule(){
        Intent intent =  new Intent(this, loginsuccess.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The crashing is happening after I press the "btnAdd"

Comment: This might be what you're seeing: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1392 - appears a fix was released 3 days ago. You can update it to the latest in the gradle file:     implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'

Comment: Thanks for respond! App for some reason is keep crashing:\

Comment: there might be an excess trailing `0` in the number, eg. Cellcom has `052` network entry code; combined with the country entry code it becomes `+972-52` - while `+972-052` is an invalid county/network entry code.

Comment: I got some SMS when I tried to check the app.. it worked the only problem is when I tried go to the next activity it crashed..

Answer (score 1):

The app is crashing because the method is not getting valid `credential` for the `phoneAuth` to work. This can be fixed by using `try` and `catch` on the `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential()` method.

In code it will look something like this:

```java
private void verifyCode(){

        String code = cd.getText().toString(); // this is OTP
        String pH = phone.getText().toString(); // this is phone number
        if(code.equals("") && pH.equals(""))
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Nothing to validate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            try {
                PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(otp, code);
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("exception",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Invalid credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

Also, you should put more `catch` or `if` statements to avoid giving `null` value in the methods.

Comment: In which scenario the method doesn't get a valid credential for the phoneAuth? I tried with two different numbers i.e. 1st a new number & 2nd a number (initially used as a testing number then removed from testing numbers), and I'm not getting OTP on the 2nd number even after remove from the testing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to define String code before calling phoneAuth function.

```
< String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            assert code != null;
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, code);

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);>
```